# What are validation loss units Keras/Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Introduction – The question pretty simple, I'm novice in the field , could not find a satisfying answer/s here on StackOverFlow.

The question(s) itself –
Accuracy units are clearly percent (%) but what does loss and validation-loss units are? how they relate to accuracy? how can I use them? What are generally benchmark target for them?
The problem is HTR/OCR character classification.

For example, this is 16th model loss 0.07 and and val loss 0.09 what they really mean?

[image: example of training output]

Comment: Losses in general do not have units, only some losses do, but in general they will not convey any information.

Comment: Yes, and also different loss constructions / formulations are so different that their loss value ranges could vary drastically from one another. For example:  a given model/architecture might have an average loss of 0.15 with an IoU loss (intersection over Union) formulation after 100 epochs while a loss such as Focal Loss or L2 loss might have an average of 0.01 loss at the same stage of training. With some other loss formulation the loss might be higher than 0.5 or 1. Hence, there is no standard unit to measure a loss across all kinds of loss formulations.

Comment: I think they do convey some information even if they do not have units that's like to say numbers don't convey information but in fact numbers were invented because they help to distill some information about counting

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that, since you have different loss functions, like @Matias Valdenegro stated, they do not have units, apart from the fact that the same value for different loss functions would yield a better/worse model/result as compared to the other **(0.15 loss for `binary-crossentropy` is different from 0.15 loss of `FocalLoss`, due to the construction of the loss function).**

However, there is difference that I would like to point out here, that was not mentioned in the above answers.

**On principle**, the lower the value of the loss function, the greater the accuracy.

**But** it is not always the case.
**[image: not always]**

In the picture above, you can see how an accuracy of 100% is along a loss of 2.0794, while an accuracy of 66,67% is along a loss of 1.8220.

Which model is better?

The not so evident(particularly for beginners) answer is: clearly the first model. The fact is that if you look at the predictions, should the second model have pApple 0.49 for all the predictions, you would have 0% accuracy(given the established threshold of 0.5 in most cases).

**Another example(not related to the picture above) is even more evident:**

Imagine that you have two models, yielding 100% accuracy on the test set.

Now suppose that, as in the example above, all your test images are apples.

When you look at the predictions however, the first model predicts a confidence of 0.6 for all apples, while the second one predicts a confidence of 0.96 for all apples. If you consider threshold-wise that if a prediction > 0.5 gives you a specific class, then the accuracy for both models is 100%.

But if you look at the loss-function values plot, you can see that the loss is much lower in the case of the second model.

**Always save/checkpoint your model according to the best loss value on your validation set.**

Comment: How do you calculate the confidence values exactly?

Comment: This depends on what you refer: one would say, in case of a binary classification, that if your model predicts 0.9 for apple and 0.1 for orange, then the model is confident 90% / 0.9 that your fruit is an orange. If we diverge a little bit, the idea of confidence for prediction could take us to Probabilistic Models --- Bayes networks.

Comment: Ok, but you wrote `the second one predicts a confidence of 0.96 for all apples`. What was the exact calculation?  Here we have 50% 3 times.

Comment: I gave another example in which you have 100% accuracy for two different models, but in the case of the first model you have 60% 3 times and in case of your second 96% 3 times, the example not related to the table above.

Comment: I modified the text of the answer in order to be clearer :D

Comment: It's ok now, I made a bit edit, to be more clearer, as if I missed -maybe my bad-, the beginner future reader can more either.

Comment: Are loss and cross-entropy interchangeable?

Comment: Cross-entropy and loss are not interchangeable. Cross-Entropy is a loss function. There are many other loss functions.